# dns_sd.h no such file or directory windows qt

Tags: c++, windows, qt, dns

I want to use the equivalent linux library libdns_sd.so on Windows.
I'm using QT/C++ to build an application using dns_sd.h
I'm facing an error, I have :

```
dns_sd.h: No such file or directory
```

On Linux, it works perfectly with this line on my .pro file :

```
LIBS += /usr/lib/x86_64-linux-gnu/libdns_sd.so
```

I don't know what to include on Windows to make it working.
I downloaded the mDNSResponder on https://opensource.apple.com/tarballs/mDNSResponder/ but I don't find the library to include.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The `LIBS` variable causes you to link to the `libdns_sd.so` shared library, this isn't related to the problem you are seeing. The compiler isn't complaining about a missing shared library, it is complaining about a missing header file, `dns_sh.h`.

On all platforms, header files have to be found in the include path. Typically on Linux when you install a dev package, the header file is placed in one of the commonly used include paths.

On Windows you'll need to configure the include path yourself. Use the `INCLUDEPATH` variable in qmake. Add the path to `dns_sd.h` on your Windows system and the program should compile... make sure to also link to the dll.

Comment: Hello Tim ! Thank you very much for your answer !
I added these lines :

win32 {
    LIBPATH=C:/Temp/mDNSResponder-576.30.4/mDNSWindows/DLL/
    INCLUDEPATH += C:/Temp/mDNSResponder-576.30.4/mDNSShared
}

Now he finds the header file but still make "undefined reference to 'DNSServiceRegister' and others functions" but the function is defined, I can see on auto complete etc.

What did I miss again ?
Thank you